# Service argument injection: "Argument 1 passed to entity constructor must be must be an instance of Entity, none given"

Tags: php, forms, service, symfony-3.2

I'm working with forms on my Symfony 3 app.

I have a **ClassType** created to create the form of a specific entity:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $currencies = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Currency')->findAll();
    $currenciesFormat = array();

    foreach($currencies as $currency){
        $currenciesFormat += array($currency->getName() .' ('. $currency->getShortName() . ')' => $currency);
    }

    $cycles = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Cycle')->findAll();
    $cyclesFormat = array();

    foreach($cycles as $cycle){
        $cyclesFormat += array($cycle->getName() => $cycle);
    }

    $builder
        ->add('currency', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Waluta',
            'choices' => $currenciesFormat,
        ))
        ->add('cycle', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Cykl',
            'choices' => $cyclesFormat,
        ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => CyclicNewsletter::class,
    ));
}
```

Also I have a universal ***POST*** action ment to handle most of the submitting (regullar *add to db* type stuff). It uses variable classnames to match many forms at once. 
For now, all it does it `var_dumps` the class it is supposed persist into the database:

```
  /**
     * @Route("/form/{url}", name="entity_form_post")
     * @Method("POST")
     *
     */
    public function formPostAction(EntityForm $entityForm, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm($entityForm->createType())
            ->add('Dodaj!', SubmitType::class)
        ;

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $formData = $form->getData();



            $em->persist($formData);

            var_dump($formData);
            exit;
    }
}
```

---

Now I want the `CyclicNewsletter` constructor to by default set the currently logged in user as `$user` field.

For this I have created a service working for the class:

```
cyclic_newsletter:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\CyclicNewsletter
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

And made the entity's **constructor** make use of the argument:

```
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    $this->date = new DateTime();
}
```

However the output I am getting when submitting the form is:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\CyclicNewsletter::__construct() must be an instance
>   of AppBundle\Entity\TokenStorage, none given, called in
>   C:\PHP\Repos\centaur\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType.php
>   on line 136

---

I have tried using a separate method inside the class, but it too requires an argument.

Is there any way I can make this work?

ps. All cache have been cleared

Edit:
 - Running `debug:container` displays the service properly.
 - Searching to my service in **appDevDebugProjectContainer.php** returns this:

```
/**
 * Gets the 'cyclic_newsletter' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\CyclicNewsletter A AppBundle\Entity\CyclicNewsletter instance
 */
protected function getCyclicNewsletterService()
{
    return $this->services['cyclic_newsletter'] = new \AppBundle\Entity\CyclicNewsletter($this->get('security.token_storage'));
}
```